# What design should I use so a class can query one of it's ancestors?

Tags: design-patterns, class-design, class-hierarchy

I'm creating an object hierarchy that is representing a table that is draw on a control. My hierarchy looks like this :

```
Table has multiple pages
Page has multiple lines
Line has multiple cells
Cell has multiple glyph
```

I want to have an option (a parameter) on the table to filter the column (cells) displayed. The client code can do something like this:

```
myTable.ShowColumns(8,12) // Will display columns 8 to 12
```

Displaying and placing cells on the control is the responsibility of the Lines objects.How can I pass the informations of which cells are to be displayed from the Table object to the Line object?

Should I give each line a reference to the table object? Should I try to pass the informations to each lines through the hierarchy each time `Table.ShowColumns()` is called?

There must be an elegant way?

Comment: Are you using inheritance for this, this is clearly a case of a Has-A relationship and not a Is-A relationship. If you're using inheritance what does the class hierarchy look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is need for a design pattern. (Or I wouldn't call it that way)
Why don't you just use double linking where childs link to the parent and vice versa?

Comment: Hi Patrick, Thanks for your answer, I agree with you design pattern was not the right term for what I was looking for. I like your idea to have a link from the child to the parents.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you refer to as *ancestors* are actually *parents* in your hierarchy - which in effect if nothing more than a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_data_structure). And with trees it is common practice to have child nodes reference their respective parents.

As to the design of the ShowColumns function, I think it should modify an internal state variable of the Lines class (which holds the cells) by virtue of a similar internal function call on the Lines class.

```
// something like this..
Table.ShowCollumns -> Table.m_lines.SetVisibleColumns -> (modify visible columns)
```

Obviously, depending on the logical mapping of columns to pages, and pages to tables, you may have to interject yet another call before calling *SetVisibleColumns* on the *Lines* class, in order to find the correct page object: `Table.FindPageWithColumns(...)` and then operate on that one.